# Is an undefined ng-bind more expensive than an ng-bind and ng-show?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Supposing `toShowVar` us undefined, which is more expensive?

```
<span ng-bind="toShowVar" ng-show="toShowVar"></span>
```

or

```
<span ng-bind="toShowVar"></span>
```

The latter would obviously not print anything on the screen if the variable is undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To explain this, first of all `ng-show` and `ng-bind` both runs at a same `priority` level. there is nothing in favor of `ng-show` to increase performance.

here to hide the content `ng-show` is not required at all. ng-show will also start watching the same (here `toShowVar`) and will perform on the watcher registered by it (changing the display property to none by adding ng-hide class). 
To explain more, if you use `ng-show='false'` and change `toShowVar` to some text in a further operation, and visit the `DOM` by debugger tool, you can check that the updated text is still available. So, obviously ng-show will not add any performance benefit here. 
If you use `ng-if` (running on a higher priority that both), it will remove element from `DOM` and further subsequent watchers will not be active until it will be re rendered to DOM, so even in case of `ng-if` you are running something extra, so it will not be faster like only `ng-bind` but faster than `ng-bind` and `ng-show` thgother.

Note: only `ng-bind` and `ng-bind ng-show` can differ in UI, if the span having some affect of CSS (maybe inline, hierarchy parent, or any ) that is visible in UI even if it is empty (something like border), otherwise, with look and feel both are same.

Answer (score 0):

`<span ng-bind="toShowVar" ng-show="toShowVar"></span>` seems to be more expensive.because `toShowVar` will be bound to `span` even if there is nothing in that.If we use `ng-if="toShowVar"` , that will be little expensive, since the angular not include this `span` element to DOM.So giving them in decreasing order

`<span ng-bind="toShowVar" ng-show="toShowVar"></span>`

`<span ng-bind="toShowVar"></span>`

`<span ng-bind="toShowVar" ng-if="toShowVar"></span>`

Answer (score 0):

If you use `ng-bind="toShowVar"` the `ng-show="toShowVar"` will be useless, because using `ng-bind` is sufficient to render the `span` with an empty content if `toShowVar` was `undefined`.

So using both of them will be more expensive due to the second *useless* test in `ng-show="toShowVar"`, as it will check again for the value of `toShowVar` and then try to add the class `.ng-hide` to the element.

**But** the difference is that with only `ng-bind` the span will be rendered in the page with empty content, and using `ng-show` will render it but with `dispaly:none` from `.ng-hide` class.

Comment: 'If you use ng-bind="toShowVar" the ng-show="toShowVar" will be useless, because using ng-bind is sufficient to hide the span if toShowVar was undefined.'

This is not right i think.

Comment: That `span` element will be there irrespective to value of ng-bind variable.

Comment: @Mr.niks Yes you are right, I just didn't explained it correctly I reformulated it: because using ng-bind is sufficient to render the span with an empty content if toShowVar was undefined